# If(AND) combination produces "You've entered too many arguments for this function" error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

hello everyone I'm here and needs help with excel
message from excel is
(you've entered too many arguments for this function)
and that my function.
=IF(AND(H2="A","B"),"group 1",IF(AND(N2H2="C","D"),"group 2",""))
please any one can help ?

Comment: `and` if for two logical tests a logical test is `h1="A"` so your first one should change to `AND(h2="A,h2="B")` however thats obviously not possible so is an odd test, potentially the second and it meant to be `and(n2="C",h2="D")`? anyway I think this should probably get you there roughly

Comment: Your may want to check whether ```OR``` instead of ```AND``` is what you need as in “… all the A and B cases of cell H2 belong to group 1 …” which “translates” to all cases where H2 is equal to A OR H2 is equal to B. The syntax for the parameters is the same as for AND as explained by InjuredCoding

Comment: You should separate the tests so you understand the logic or your logic…

Answer (score 1):

The first condition to test within the IF statement "`AND(H2="A","B")`" will always return false - as this tests "`Is H2 = "A" ? AND "Is '"B"'`?

H2 cannot equal "A" and "B" simultaneously, and besides, even if you wanted to test that you'd have to use "`AND(H2="A", H2="B")`.

- Imagine someone asking you the Q *"Is H2 = "A"?"*
- You could answer this if you knew what was in cell H2 (like Excel does) - and you could answer 'True' (yes) or 'False' (no).
- But if you were asked is "B" as well? you would probably be quite puzzled - perhaps you would reply *"Is "B" what as well"?*

Excel would also be puzzled and in such circumstances the default response is 'False' (until proven otherwise!)

---

The 2nd AND statement is the wrong syntax - see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9) for some examples of how to use the AND statement.

This is probably why you are seeing the error you see -  again:

- If someone asked you "Is N2H2="C" and is "B" as well?
- You wouldn't know which cell I was referring to (N2H2 does not exist in Excel)
- Further, you wouldn't know what to say to "Is "B"?" (Is it a consonent? Is it capital? Is it the 2nd letter of the alphabet? Is it *what*?

Using this equation Excel will not return an error "too many arguments", it will return "invalid name error" (because there is no such thing as "N2H2" as far as Excel is concerned")

[image: invalid name entry]

---

You need to use the following generic syntax for AND statements of this type:

```
AND(cell 1=some value1, cell 2= some value2) - not AND(cell1cell2=some value1, some value2)
```

i.e. this would be correct syntax:

```
=IF(AND(H2="A",N2="B"),"group 1",IF(AND(H2="D",N2="C"),"group 2",""))
```

(but it assumes you are trying to test cell N2 = B in the first AND statement because it's impossible for cell H2 to equal both A and B at the same time as I've said above)

As someone has pointed out in the comments - if you're testing whether H2 can be "A" OR "B" then simply use the OR statement - i.e. something like this:

```
=IF(OR(H2="A",H2="B"),"group 1",IF(AND(H2="D",N2="C"),"group 2",""))
```

---

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/and-function-5f19b2e8-e1df-4408-897a-ce285a19e9d9